# Is there any Custom ROM Availabe For Android TV

Tags: android, android-tv, rom, custom-rom

I want to develop Custom ROM for Android TV. I know about Mobile ROM but i don't have any idea about Android TV Custom ROM. While searching about Android TV custom ROM i found that The LHG Releases the First Build of AOSP TV for the 96Boards HiKey Platform. Will it help me to develop ROM for another TV device?

https://wiki.linaro.org/LHG/Build-AndroidTV-For-Hikey